Mistake on car insurance policy about use of car (commuting/social)
After buying my car insurance, with me as the main driver and my husband and daughter as other named drivers, there is a mistake in the policy.
My husband uses the car for pleasure and commuting to work, but they put him as only social. I, the policy holder and car owner, use the car only for social, but they put me as commuting as well.
So basically, the switch the car use between my husband and myself, and now is wrong.
I would like to fix the mistake they made, but I don't know if this will be consider a wrong on my side and if it will bring me any problems.
I cannot prove I entered the right details and they made the mistake.

What are you afraid of when telling them to fix it? That they charge you for the change? As long as nothing has happened, you should always be able to request a change of the contract (maybe you change the job and now need to use the car as well)

There is generally a grace period, especially for details like this. Call them up ASAP. Stuff like this is routine.

well, usually the "main" driver is the one that commutes, so this seems like a simple mistake to be corrected rather than a legal concern.

Changes also occur quite legitimately: you and your husband decide to swap cars, somebody gets a new job that works from home, etc. The key is to report the changes as soon as possible.

Mistakes happen all the time. You fix them. If you were actually trying to defraud the insurance company, you wouldn't tell them about the mistake.

If they made the mistake (you did this over the phone instead of online for example), insist that any change fees are waived. However if you've bought the insurance in the last 14 days, legally there should be no change fees (but some insurers will try and weasel out of it).

united-kingdom
It's likely that your policy documents say you must tell the insurer if any information is incorrect.
Immediately tell an insurer about any mistakes in the policy. In such circumstances it doesn't matter how it happened so much as it is rectified as soon as possible. It might cost you more but it's imperative you make sure the insurer has no reason/excuse to 'void' (invalidate) the policy and to not pay out in the event of an accident.
Scenario:
Alice is insured for Social, Domestic and Pleasure and Commuting (SDP+C).
Bob is insured for SDP.
One day Bob has an accident on his commute. The insurer refuses to pay out - or reduces the pay-out - on the basis that Bob wasn't insured for commuting.
You don't want that to happen. Even if after complaining you eventually get a ruling wholly or partially in your favour, it will have cost you lots of time and stress.
(Also, if your policy is void then there are Road Traffic Act implications.)

The insurance policy is a contract between the consumer and the insurer.
The consumer provides information about the risks to be insured and the insurer agrees to insure against these risks in return for the price paid by the consumer.
Commuting usually occurs at peak times when the risk is considered to be worse than at non-peak times (and priced accordingly).

You're mentally framing this in the wrong way, it's not like you're going to be accused of deception.  It's good enough to say that roles change.  So you call them up and say the correct roles are X and Y, and they make the change on your policy and they really don't need to ask if it's a change or an error correction.
The important part is it's corrected ASAP and before a claim.
You could have problems with your claim if the facts they have are untrue AND as a result you are paying a lower premium than you should have been.
